# Query method issue on rails upgrade to 6.1.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6.1

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmnJs.png)

Upgraded rails from 6.0.3 to 6.1.5 but having issues with query methods like eager_load and references.

```
class Note < ApplicationRecord
      has_many :sellers
end

class Seller < ApplicationRecord
      belongs_to :note
end
```

So when I try `Note.eager_load(:sellers)` or `Note.includes(:sellers).references(:sellers)`
an `ArgumentError` occurs:

> ArgumentError (expected 5 got 6)

Is it something related to rails upgrade issue or Did I miss something when upgrading rails.

Answer (score 3):

To all those concerned, It was because of rails_select_on_includes gem which is not needed anymore after 6.0.3.